# Javascript if statement showing falsy when truthy on Safari (Works on chrome)

Tags: javascript

I am designing a quiz app. The code snip below from the .js file for a .html file detects when the user has selected the correct answer. However is Safari, when the code is truthy, the falsy result is shown.

```
// Gets the correct answer for the question
const correct = quiz.correct[x]

for(check of checkboxes){ // all checkbox inputs user can choose from
    if(check.checked === true){ // can only choosea signle checkbox
        const ans = check.nextElementSibling.innerText.substring(3) // The answer from the selected checkbox
        console.log(ans + ' ' + typeof ans) // Confirming the selected answer is right
        console.log(correct + ' ' + typeof correct) // Confirming the correct answer for the question is right
        if(correct === ans){ // Does not work on Safari...
            console.log('true')
        }else{
            console.log('false')
        }
    }
}
```

The:

> if(correct === ans){

gives the incorrect result is Safari. it works as expected in Chrome.

This is the screen shot from the running code in safari with the console.logs:

[image]

This is the same code running in Chrome:

[image]

I have tried some very basic test code with an if formula that works as expected. But for some reason the code above does not work.

I have also done multiple apps with just as complex code and never had an issue.

Does anybody know how to make this work? The end users will more than likely be using Safari.

Comment: Have you actually tried to debug the values of `correct` and `ans`?

Comment: Can you include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? We cant debug a screenshot nor code that is missing values.

Comment: Maybe, you use just double equal (==) instead of triple (===), so it compares only the value, and not the type, and add trim() to remove the spaces around strings.

Answer (score -1):

Use `if(correct.trim() === ans.trim())`

Comment: This worked!! Thank you very much.

Comment: Why would I need to trim() in Safari and not Chrome??

Comment: Nobody can answer that as you didn't provide this information in your question... We don't know how you've created the form, nor the checkboxes inside the form